# Positioning not working when use SVG image

Tags: html, css, svg

Trying to position the green div over SVGIcon component, but when I resize my screen then the positioning is not working properly, the green inner div moves away from the white svg image, as you see in the image below. Any help from you will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

See the image below:

[image]

// if I resized my screen then it look like this:

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="markar-container">
    <button>
      <h1>Pin</h1>
      <div class="markar-items">
        <SvgIcon class="union-layer" />
        <div class="color-overlay">
          <div class="text">AA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SvgIcon from "./icons/SvgIcon.vue";
export default {
  name: "Test",
  components: { SvgIcon },

  data() {
    return {
      text: "Ello",
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.markar-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.markar-items {
  /* display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.union-layer {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.color-overlay {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #3ac371;
  position: absolute;
  top: 109px;
  left: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

.color-overlay:hover {
  background: #9f1853;
}

</style>
```

Comment: set position: relative;  in  .markar-items , and element inside position: absolute; and use % instead of px

Answer (score 1):

If the container of the two (SVG and green circle) is positioned relative, then you can give the green circle an absolute position that refers to the container.

```css
h1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.markar-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.markar-items {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.color-overlay {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #3ac371;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

.color-overlay:hover {
  background: #9f1853;
}
```

```html
<div class="markar-container">
  <button>
      <h1>Pin</h1>
      <div class="markar-items">
        <svg width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="display: block;">
          <rect width="10" height="10" fill="yellow"/>
          <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="white" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".3" />
        </svg>
        <div class="color-overlay">
          <div class="text">AA</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @chrwahl, I will check soon and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the text be a part of the SVG? Then you don't need to worry about positioning elements absolute.

```css
h1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.markar-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.markar-items {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

circle.hover:hover {
  fill: #9f1853;
}

text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="markar-container">
  <button>
      <h1>Pin</h1>
      <div class="markar-items">
        <svg width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="display: block;">
          <rect width="10" height="10" fill="yellow"/>
          <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="white" stroke="gray" stroke-width=".3" />
          <circle class="hover" cx="5" cy="5" r="3.5" fill="green" />
          <text font-size="4" fill="white" x="5" y="5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">AA</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @chrwahl for the tips, Now my positioning works properly. I was also trying to add Focus around the svg image, so when tab the svg should have  border-style: dashed; So I gave my button a class name like below, but it does not work. Any help on this ....
.btn-focus:focus {
  /* border-right-color: black; */
  background-color: black;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 4px;
  outline: none;
}
.btn-focus:focus .color-overlay {
  background: #9f1853;
}